# How to hide/unhide the router-link button for a specific component in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vue-component, vue-cli-3

I am using router-link as the button to navigate between different components.
Is there any way to hide the component for a particular component.

```
<router-link :to="{path: prevPage }" tag="button" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more ? Please.

Comment: i am using the above <router-link> tab to go back to the previous components in my page. i need it to be hidden in my index page. is that understandable ?

Comment: You need the path itself to be hidden? Or to not render a component coming from another component?

Comment: i need that button not to be shown or visible in my page for a particluar component. is that possible ?

Comment: Gotcha. Is it possible that you include more code? Just to have more context and see if i can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the path of the current route by two ways

```
v-if="$route.path != '/'"
```

or

```
v-if="$router.currentRoute.path != '/'"
```

They both returns a string that equals the path of the current route, always resolved as an absolute path.

You can check the documentation :
https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties

You can check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Farouk_Mekkaoui/7xvpje08/12/

Comment: This hides the button alright, but not displays the button for other components. do you know why ?

Comment: You mean that even when the path is different from '/' you still can't see it ?

Comment: Yes, it hides the button for all the components

Comment: Try to use $route.path without the this or $router.currentRoute.path

Answer (score 1):

The answer above helped get me most of the way there but something that worked a little better for me using named routes was:

```
v-if="$router.currentRoute.name != 'routeNameHere'"
```